# Count down to a target datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time, timer, clock

I am trying to create a program which takes a target time (like 16:00 today) and counts down to it, printing each second like this:

```
...
5
4
3
2
1
Time reached
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This is a reasonable question to which a naive solution won't work. The obvious approach is to have a loop in which you repeatedly sleep for a second and then print the time remaining, but since the non-sleep operations take time to execute, the loop will drift off taking exactly one second to execute. If you're keeping track of the seconds remaining with a decrementing integer, you'll therefore be late reaching 0; but if you calculate the time each iteration by getting the current time, you may skip a second in your output. That nuance is interesting, and this question didn't deserve closure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this using python **`threading`** module also, something like this :

```
from datetime import datetime
import threading

selected_date = datetime(2017,3,25,1,30)

def countdown() : 
    t = threading.Timer(1.0, countdown).start()
    diff = (selected_date - datetime.now())
    print diff.seconds
    if diff.total_seconds() <= 1 :    # To run it once a day
        t.cancel()

countdown()
```

For printing "Click Now" when countdown gets over, you can do something like this :

```
from datetime import datetime
import threading

selected_date = datetime(2017,3,25,4,4)

def countdown() : 
    t = threading.Timer(1.0, countdown)
    t.start()
    diff = (selected_date - datetime.now())
    if diff.total_seconds() <= 1 :    # To run it once a day
        t.cancel()
        print "Click Now"
    else :
        print diff.seconds
countdown()
```

This will result in something like this **every second** :

```
2396
2395
2394
2393
...
```

Comment: `.total_seconds()` if you want it to work over multiple days. otherwise it will go off at that time on *any* day.

Comment: @TemporalWolf The OP asked for every day upto that time, right ?

Comment: You are right. This should work if you trigger when the time is 0.

Comment: @SatishGarg When I try to run the code it says there is no attribute called seconds

Comment: Check the datetime import and the brackets.

Comment: @TemporalWolf  Why does it say there is no attribute called seconds for 'none types' when I run it

Comment: @SatishGarg.   That is what I originally thought was the problem so I copied and pasted the code above.

Comment: Other wise this works super well.

Comment: @Kg123 Is it working now ?

Comment: @SatishGarg.   Yes it works. Thanks a lot for the help it is great. Now I need it to say "CLICK NOW" at 0 seconds. I have tried a few ways but I can't get it too work. Do you know how do it. Thanks for being so helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just did it. So I added the if statement but it still prints 0. Is there any way to get around it

Comment: @SatishGarg.   Is it possible to get around it printing zero

Comment: -1; since instantiating the `Timer()` object will take some time, over time the number of milliseconds in the times at which `countdown()` is called will drift (e.g. first call at 12:00:00.0000, then at 12:00:01.0003, then 12:00:02.0005, and so on). Over sufficient time, this drift will add up to over a second and will cause a second to be skipped from the countdown (e.g. the countdown might go ..., `26`, `25`, `23`, `22`, ...).

Comment: @MarkAmery Agreed it has an execution time attached to every call but everything does and as OP needs to reinstantiate the countdown every day, that would not amount more than to few milli-seconds. Do you suppose a while loop will be better?