# How to have a prompt show up on canvas screen and delete

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, timer, tkinter-canvas

I am currently trying to make a program which counts down to a specific time every day. I have got the timer finished, but now I need the prompt to show up on the canvas. How would I make the seconds show up (prompt) and then delete and show the next seconds up (next prompt). Thanks a lot for any help

```
from datetime import datetime
import threading
import time
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, heihgt=400)
canvas.pack()

selected_date = datetime(2017,3,24,16,16)

def countdown() :
    t = threading.Timer(1.0, countdown).start()
    s = (selected_date - datetime.now()).seconds
    print(s, "seconds until click")
    if s == 0:
    print("CLICK NOW")


countdown()
```

This is the current code I have now. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't use threads for a simple countdown timer. Search this site, there are several examples of timers that user `after` instead of threads.

Comment: @BryanOakley.   Threads was recommended by other users and I feel that it was the most efficient at the time

Comment: For this specific tasks, threads are pretty much the most _inefficient_ solution.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you shouldn't use threading (my guess is that you got the idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43007345/6622817) question) with tkinter. You should use .after instead since it supports how tkinter operates. Here is a example on how to use it (using the your framework):

```
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

selected_date = datetime(2017,3,24,16,16)
time = Label(canvas) # creates a label
time.pack()
def countdown() :
    s = (selected_date - datetime.now()).seconds # calculates the seconds left
    time['text']=str(s) + " seconds until click" # change the text of the label
    if s == 0:
        time.pack_forget() # hide the label when time is up
        clicker = Button(canvas, text="CLICK NOW") # creates a button with the text CLICK ME
        clicker.pack()
        return 
    canvas.after(1000, countdown) # continue till the time is up


canvas.after(1000, countdown) # 1000 ms == 1 second
tk.mainloop()
```

This example creates a label that displays the amount of second from the selected time to now, as requested in the question. And creates a button that says CLICK NOW when the time is up.

Note: when using .after, the first argument of time is in **ms** which means 1000 ms = 1 sec.

Also Note: Threading *could* work if you're **not** using tkinter and that you used it *correctly*.  But never with tkinter.